# Wrapping DLL to log certain functions

Tags: c++, dll, word-wrap

So if I have both a complete set of headers and a .lib file for a C++ dll, is it possible to create a second C++ dll that wraps the original and allows me to see when certain functions are called and then it just calls the original functions? Is there a simpler way of doing this? I also am only concerned about a couple of functions in a large dll

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is *possible*. Why wouldn't you think it is? It is even possible to define an exported function to be an alias for an exported function in another DLL, to pass through the functions you are not interested in.

Where you might run into a problem is when software uses the original `.lib` file to static link to the original DLL. Since you likely wouldn't be able to recompile such software to use your `.lib` files, your DLL would need to have the same filename as the original DLL, and replicate the original DLL's exports *exactly* (names and ordinal).

Another problem would be if the original DLL exports a class that software uses.  Those would be harder to replicate.

A different approach would be to not replace the original DLL at all, but instead to inject your DLL into the target process and then [detour](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/) just the DLL exports that you are interested in.